# Kotlin: Is there a way to clean up number overloads?

Tags: numbers, type-conversion, kotlin, data-conversion

Often I find myself creating lots of overloads for number types because Kotlin  doesn't do implicit conversions for non-literals. This results in a huge amount of duplicate overload functions which is tons and tons of boilerplate.

An example of the pain I have doing this can be seen here: https://github.com/Jire/Arrowhead/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jire/arrowhead/Source.kt

I understand the reason why implicit conversions can cause bugs, but I think in most cases, especially for "enlargement" conversions like `Byte -> Int` and `Int -> Long` where data isn't lost there should be a better way.

So... my question is how do you deal with this? Are there any creative ways to solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, why don't you use JNR instead of JNA? JNR is much faster.

Comment: @SerCe My performance testing against direct-mapped JNA shows negligible performance gains, and sometimes performance loss.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question: you can use a generic function with [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/). Then it will accept any subtype of `Number`. Then you can convert the value into any other numeric type:

```
fun boo(x: Number) {
    val y = x.toLong()
    println(y is Long)
}
```

The only downside of this is autoboxing, but that should not matter for your case.

Regarding the code you posted: I believe you have some architectural errors which cause this situation. Here is your API without too much details:

```
interface Source {
    fun read(address: Long, data: Pointer, bytesToRead: Int) 

    fun read(address: Int, data: Pointer, bytesToRead: Int) = read(address.toLong(), data, bytesToRead)
    fun read(address: Long, data: Memory, bytesToRead: Int = data.size().toInt()) = read(address, data as Pointer, bytesToRead)
    fun read(address: Int, data: Memory, bytesToRead: Int = data.size().toInt()) = read(address.toLong(), data, bytesToRead)
    fun read(address: Long, struct: Struct, bytesToRead: Int = struct.size()) = read(address, struct.pointer, bytesToRead)
    fun read(address: Int, struct: Struct, bytesToRead: Int = struct.size()) = read(address.toLong(), struct, bytesToRead)
    fun read(address: Long, bytesToRead: Int): Memory = TODO()
    fun read(address: Int, bytesToRead: Int) = read(address.toLong(), bytesToRead)


    fun byte(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 1).getByte(offset)
    fun byte(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = byte(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun short(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 2).getShort(offset)
    fun short(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = short(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun char(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 2).getChar(offset)
    fun char(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = char(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun int(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 4).getInt(offset)
    fun int(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = int(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun long(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 8).getLong(offset)
    fun long(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = long(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun float(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 4).getFloat(offset)
    fun float(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = float(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun double(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = read(address, 8).getDouble(offset)
    fun double(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = double(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun boolean(address: Long, offset: Long = 0) = byte(address, offset).unsign() > 0
    fun boolean(address: Int, offset: Long = 0) = boolean(address.toLong(), offset)

    fun write(address: Long, data: Pointer, bytesToWrite: Int)
    fun write(address: Int, data: Pointer, bytesToWrite: Int) = write(address.toLong(), data, bytesToWrite)
    fun write(address: Long, data: Memory, bytesToWrite: Int = data.size().toInt())
            = write(address, data as Pointer, bytesToWrite)
    fun write(address: Int, data: Memory, bytesToWrite: Int = data.size().toInt())
            = write(address.toLong(), data, bytesToWrite)
    fun write(address: Long, struct: Struct, bytesToWrite: Int = struct.size())
            = write(address, struct.pointer, bytesToWrite)
    fun write(address: Int, struct: Struct, bytesToWrite: Int = struct.size())
            = write(address.toLong(), struct, bytesToWrite)

    // ...
}
```

This API works with `Long` for `address`, but also accepts `Int` for some reason. I think you should peek one (e.i `Long`) and let the consumer worry about converting `Int` to `Long`. This is not a responsibility of an API. Besides, if a consumer works with an API which uses `Long` for `address`, he will usually use `Long` to manipulate with addresses on his side too. This simplifies the API and saves on `Int` to `Long` and back conversions, which improves the performance.

Comment: For my case performance is very important, the functions need to be called thousands of times per second. Number is something to know though!

Comment: Less than a couple of millions calls per second is not much. I advice you measure your program w/ and w/o boxing to see if there is a notable difference